# Count the occurance of unique values based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of times a number (Knumber) occurs for each of the categories (category), below is my sample data.

```
Knumber category
K9  red
K1  white
K1  white
K9  white
K6  blue
```

I'm attempting make it into the following using pandas.

```
Knumber category    count
K9  red 1
K1  white   2
K9  white   1
K6  blue    1
```

I've fiddled around with value.counts using `df['Knumber'].value_counts()` but obviously that only counts Knumbers, can you please help me bring my other column 'category' into the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pandas groupby and the size function to get the count. The agg method allows us to pass a name for the aggregated column.

```
 (df
.groupby(['Knumber','category'])
.agg(count= ('category','size'))
.reset_index()
 )


   Knumber  category    count
0   K1  white   2
1   K6  blue    1
2   K9  red 1
3   K9  white   1
```